# Change text colour of desktop icons on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, colors, icons, desktop-customization

As the title says, is there any way to change the colour of text for the icons on your desktop in Windows 10?

I have a lot of nature backgrounds so white tends to blend in. I have made them bold but that isn't really enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Is there any way to change the desktop icon text colour in Windows 10?

> I struggled with this for some time but I found a way:
>
> - If you have the background set to picture, set it to Solid color.
> - Chances are it's black by default.
> - This is forcing a white font color regardless what you select for a picture.
> - Change it to say orange, which will make the font color black.
> - Now change the background back to picture, and you should have a black icon font color.

Source [Desktop Icon Color Change - Accessibility Option](http://www.tenforums.com/customization/14921-desktop-icon-color-change-accessibility-option.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have come across this solution but none of the solid colours available in Windows 10 seem to make the font colour black! I haven't even got white as a solid background colour to select?

Comment: Sorry! Orange does make the text black - I'm not sure how I missed that. To be honest it hasn't made the icons anymore readable, but hopefully this question will still be of some help to other users.

Comment: Same here. Doesn't work with Orange. Using Windows 10 x64. This frustrated Win10 user reports the same: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/icon-label-text-color-will-not-change-and-drop/c237a16a-6d76-4f36-9496-d5a6e60d39de

Comment: This is not working anymore and there seems to be no other solution :-(

Comment: Seems to work for me.  Make sure you pick a light background.  None of the ones Microsoft provides seem to be light enough, but you can click the "+" button to use a custom color.  I set mine to a light blue (#77aaff) which produces black text for me.