# Change text color of desktop icons in Windows 10

Tags: fonts, colors, icons

There was a previous question on this at
[Change text colour of desktop icons on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1015566/change-text-colour-of-desktop-icons-on-windows-10)
but it has been closed.

The answer there worked for an hour or two, then didn't..
The suggestion was to set background to solid color orange (which would automatically make the icon font color the desired black), then change background to PICTURE, and font would stay black.

This worked momentarily, but now I see it has reverted to white, and now selecting orange for the solid color does NOT (any more) change icon font color to black.  How do I get it back?

Comment: That question is "protected" not "closed", so it's still open and valid. If you'd like newer/different answers to the existing question, earn some Rep and place a Bounty on it (see help section for more info).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change text colour of desktop icons on Windows 10](http://superuser.com/questions/1015566/change-text-colour-of-desktop-icons-on-windows-10)

Comment: Terminology aside, I cannot post/explain my problem there...something about points?

Comment: I would add that my issue, while related, is different.  The offered solution has failed to continue working, and that is likely a different issue than solving it in the first place.

Comment: I guess nothing further is coming.  Too bad.  I would have appreciated help.

Comment: [What should I do if no one answers my question?](http://superuser.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: What's the point of closing the question as a duplicate if the answer to the duplicate didn't work for the OP?